# Первое отрабатывание при скроле

Tags: jquery

Есть следующий код.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
var positionEl = $(".top").offset().top;
var positionElBot = $(".bottom").offset().top;
var currentScrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight
if (currentScrollTop >= positionEl && currentScrollTop <= positionElBot) {
  $(".dial10").knob();
  $({
    animatedVal: 0
  }).animate({
    animatedVal: 10
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: "swing",
    step: function() {
      $(".dial10").val(Math.ceil(this.animatedVal)).trigger("change");
    }
  });
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <div class=" circle">
    <input type="text" value="10" class="dial10" data-thickness="0.15" data-fgColor="#00BD9D">
    <p>На 10% дешевле заводской цены</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Это код по отрисовке круговой диаграммы, причем `.knob` - это функция из библиотеки для отрисовки диаграммы. В чем суть: диаграмма отрисовывается каждый раз, когда происходит скролл в периоде, который занимает блок `top`. Надо, чтобы отработал только один раз, а при следующем скролле не отрабатывался. Как этого можно добиться?

Comment: ну если код выглядит именно так, как вы его написали, то суть проблемы вообще не понятна, представленный JS отрабатывает сразу при загрузке страницы и при скролле не вызывается

Comment: @MasterAlex на самом деле там внутри библиотеки есть биндинги на wheel и надо конретней смотреть, какая версия, что происходит... https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob/blob/master/js/jquery.knob.js#L671-L672

Comment: @Sergalas вы можете выложить работающий код с той версий библиотеки, которая у вас подключена?

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, ждём пояснения от автора, я всё таки надеюсь на то, что скрипт обёрнут в функцию срабатывающую по скроллу, иначе все манипуляции автора по вычислению условия совсем теряют смысл :)

Comment: Извеняюсь что так долго да скрипт другой если точно то я поправил добавил скролы но код не доконца живой. Скачал именно от туда. Насчет бидингов вопрос мне получается надо mousewheel.js качать? Я просто ими ни когда не пользовался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я нашел ответ написал так не знаю правильно или нет но работает

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var positionEl = $(".top").offset().top;
var positionElBot = $(".bottom").offset().top;
var currentScrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight
if (currentScrollTop >= positionEl && currentScrollTop <= positionElBot) {
  $(".dial10").knob();
  $({
    animatedVal: 0
  }).animate({
    animatedVal: 10
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: "swing",
    step: function() {
      $(".dial10").val(Math.ceil(this.animatedVal)).trigger("change");
    }
  });
  $(".circle input").off('animate') 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте после первого выполнения делать `$(window).unbind('scroll');`

Comment: первый вопрос а как определить что первый скрол совершен? Второй вопрос мне не надо отклчать скрол мне надо что бы после первого скрола функция не отрабатывалась но скрол работатал.

Answer (score 0):

Если неохота долго разбираться, можно использовать такой костыль:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if(!$('body').hasClass('show-graph')) {
    var positionEl = $(".top").offset().top;
    var positionElBot = $(".bottom").offset().top;
    var currentScrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight
    if (currentScrollTop >= positionEl && currentScrollTop <= positionElBot) {
        $(".dial10").knob();
        $({
            animatedVal: 0
        }).animate({
            animatedVal: 10
        }, {
            duration: 2000,
            easing: "swing",
            step: function() {
                $(".dial10").val(Math.ceil(this.animatedVal)).trigger("change");
            }
        });
        $('body').addClass('show-graph');
    }
}
```

Comment: И собствено, что изменится? Функция выполняется если есть класс который создается при скроле. А мне надо что бы после первого скрола запустилась функция и больше не запускалась.

Comment: Извиняюсь, поспешил и забыл написать отрицание, нужно чтобы было `if(!$('body').hasClass('show-graph'))`. Исправил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Так должно сработать

```
 # вешаем на событие scroll обработчик.
 $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    #при первой отработке снимаем обработчик
    #this - это window
    $(this).off('scroll');
    ...
 })
```

Comment: А вы можете объяснить как это сработает ?

Comment: Добавил комментарии в код. Собственно, даже не знаю что тут объяснять. Сначала вешаем обработчик на scroll. Во время обработки выполняем Ваш код и сразу снимаем обработчик scroll. Таким образом в следующий раз он не отработает.

Comment: Хотел многое на писать но напишу одно не работает.

Comment: А вообще нет я извиняюсь за работало спасибо. Но проблема в том что мне не надо скрол отключать.

Answer (score 0):

А вот такой вот костыль не подойдёт?
http://jsfiddle.net/Lt43dz7v/